# Xcode Editor menu options are grayed out?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to choose vertical Guide, but even on the other options I can choose they're all grayed out.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Hi Moe. Try to select the components those you want on the left menu, like the Label and so do on... then the guide will be available.

Comment: @J.Lopes that’s exactly what I’ve done. Either way, I was following a YouTube channel creating this code and we were on the same exact screen when the tutorial chose the vertical guide. I think there’s something wrong in the settings or something lol

Comment: Update: Still can’t get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have the main view selected. You can't add guides to that. If you want to put guides on your labels, you have to do them separately.

Comment: Why can’t a guide be added to the main view?